# Cannot change default Selenium browser in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am creating a Rails application which I'm testing with RSpec and Capybara. When running test cases, Firefox is displaying the following error:

[image: Screenshot]

I have attempted to change the default browser by using the following code in `spec_helper.rb`; but it's not working.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Comment: it seems more like a Firefox issue. If you try to visit the same url manually (not through your spec), care you able to visit it?

Comment: @fabersky: I can't using another tab in same window but I can view the same page by using another window.

Comment: btw, if you want to use the driver you added with your code, you should add this to your spec_helper: `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` (or `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium` , it depends on your needs)

Answer (score 1):

In your `spec_helper.rb`, configure a new driver:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

You can give it the name you want (in this case, `selenium` but you can call it whatever you want, e.g. `selenium_chrome` or `driver_I_like`)

Then set the new driver as the one you want to use:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

In case some of your specs are using `js`, e.g.

```
describe 'some stuff which requires js', js: true do
 ...
end
```

set the driver as

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

To change Capybara browser may try to set `javascript_driver`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```